# Graph representation - Can these edge lists be considered the same?

Tags: graph-theory

I have found several datasets online that contain edge lists in an somewhat unordered fashion, skipping some vertices and not starting at 0, like this:

```
source     destination
7          5
1          4
5          7
3          2
2          1
7          3
```

Each row represents an edge. In the example above, the graph is directed, but it can also be undirected (so both directions will be added). The set of vertices is `{1,2,3,4,5,7}` **(note: I skipped 6 here)**.

An analysis tool that I have requires each vertex to start from 0 and does "not skip" any numbers (I believe because they are using a COO representation internally or something). In other words, I would have to translate (re-label the vertices) the above edge list to the following to be able to use it for the analysis tool:

```
source     destination
0          1
2          3
1          0
4          5
5          2
0          4
```

Similarly, each line represents an edge in the graph. Note here that because I 'converted' the previous edge list to this type of format, the following vertices were created: `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`. Note that the vertex 7 in the previous edge list becomes 0; 5 becomes 1 etc.

The properties of this graph seem to be the same (e.g. average clustering coefficient, average degree).

But am I perhaps missing something? Are these indeed the same?

Comment: You should explain the formatting of you datasets. What do these tables mean? Is the set of vertices $\{0,1, \ldots \}$ and is there an edge between any two vertices appearing in the same row? If so, is the graph directed?

Comment: Hi @StefanMesken, thanks for the comment! Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my post slightly. I hope it makes more sense now. Exactly, each row means that there exists 1 edge between the two vertices. The graph can be considered directed, but undirected is also possible (for the latter, both directions will be added in separate rows). If you have any more questions please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your conversion process, but if all you did is relabel the vertices, then of course the graphs are the same in the sense of being isomorphic.

Comment: Hi @quasi, yes, my apologies, indeed I only relabel the vertices to start from 0 essentially. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: In the converted format, why does $0$ map to $1$?

Comment: The edge (0,1) in the converted format is essentially representing the edge (7,5) from the original format. In other words, every vertex in the original format that has label '7', became '0' in the converted format. And every vertex in the original format that has label '5' becomes '1' in the converted format. The exact reason it is (0,1) is because my 'conversion' tool starts by selecting the vertex, in this case 7, and checks whether it already exists in my 'ordered' collection. Since it does not, it assigns 0. It goes on to 5, which does not exist as well, so it adds it as 1.

Comment: This goes on for all the vertices up until it selects one that already was 'relabeled'. E.g., if it it selects 7 again from the original list, it knows that it has to use 0. I might have over complicated my explanation. But indeed, relabeling the vertices is an easy way to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are exactly the same graph. (More precisely, they're isomorphic graphs.)

You can reassure yourself by writing down a [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism). When you're relabeling the graph, you're defining a bijection $\varphi : \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7\} \to \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ from the vertex set of the old graph to the vertex set of the new, with $$\varphi(7)=0,\, \varphi(5)=1,\, \varphi(1)=2,\, \varphi(4)=3,\, \varphi(3)=4,\, \varphi(2)=5.$$
Your new table is equivalent to the old table, because you're just writing down

```
source     destination
ϕ(7)       ϕ(5)
ϕ(1)       ϕ(4)
ϕ(5)       ϕ(7)
ϕ(3)       ϕ(2)
ϕ(2)       ϕ(1)
ϕ(7)       ϕ(3)
```

In other words, $(i,j)$ is an edge of the old graph if and only if $(\varphi(i), \varphi(j))$ is an edge of the new graph, which is precisely the definition of a graph isomorphism.

All properties that don't care about the labels on vertices should stay the same. Obviously if your analysis tool tells you "vertices $a$, $b$, $c$ form a cycle", you should apply $\varphi^{-1}$ to those before interpreting the result in the context of the old graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!